# Sidebar Nav Link Active using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, laravel

my sidebar navigation link is not active. it gets activated for 1 sec and resets to inactive again.i tried following jquery for this:

```
$(".nav a p").on("click", function() {
    $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
});
```

and my side bar code navation item is

```
 <!-- Sidebar Menu -->
      <nav class="mt-2">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="false">
          <!-- Add icons to the links using the .nav-icon class
               with font-awesome or any other icon font library -->
          <li class="nav-item has-treeview menu-open">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link active">
              <i class="nav-icon fa fa-dashboard"></i>
              <p>
                Dashboard
                <i class="right fa fa-angle-left"></i>
              </p>
            </a>
            <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="{{route('home')}}" class="nav-link">
                  <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>Main</p>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
             </li>
            <li class="nav-item has-treeview">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                <i class="nav-icon fa fa-book"></i>
              <p>
                Posts
                <i class="right fa fa-angle-left"></i>
              </p>
            </a>
            <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="{{route('posts.index')}}" class="nav-link">
                  <i class="nav-icon fa fa-book"></i>
                  <p>All Posts</p>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>    
      </nav>
```

i am unable to figure out whats wrong with jquery. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you removing the 'active' class and adding it again with that jquery? Doesn't really make sense to me. It gets inactive because you are removing the active class.

Answer (score 0):

You should really be listening to the anchor and not the paragraph. For the sake of this demo, I used `e.preventDefault()` to keep the hyperlinks from changing `URL`s. You'll want to remove that. Also, for efficiency, I'm using event delegation, which yields better for performance if/when the menu scales.

> Event delegation refers to the process of using event propagation
>   (bubbling) to handle events at a higher level in the DOM than the
>   element on which the event originated. [source](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```js
$(".nav-sidebar").on("click", ".nav-link", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".nav-link").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.nav-link {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-link p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="mt-2">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="false">
    <!-- Add icons to the links using the .nav-icon class
               with font-awesome or any other icon font library -->
    <li class="nav-item has-treeview menu-open">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link active">
        <i class="nav-icon fa fa-dashboard"></i>
        <p>
          Dashboard
          <i class="right fa fa-angle-left"></i>
        </p>
      </a>
      <ul class="nav nav-treevhttps://jsfiddle.net/tro45vLx/3/#tidyiew">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="{{route('home')}}" class="nav-link">
            <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
            <p>Main</p>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item has-treeview">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link">
        <i class="nav-icon fa fa-book"></i>
        <p>
          Posts
          <i class="right fa fa-angle-left"></i>
        </p>
      </a>
      <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="{{route('posts.index')}}" class="nav-link">
            <i class="nav-icon fa fa-book"></i>
            <p>All Posts</p>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0th9qvc8/1/)

Comment: i tried above jQuery mentioned and it activated the nav item but hyperlink are not working now any solution?

Comment: @JasbinKarki I mentioned in the answer that you can remove `e.preventDefault();` (2nd line in the above `JavaScript`). I added that in only to show that the highlighting was clearly working.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".nav a.nav-link").on("click", function(e) {

    if($(this).attr('href') == '#'){
        // href url is not specified, assuming its an ajax call 
        // If not you can remove this
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    // Remove all active classes
    $('.nav .nav-link').removeClass('active');

    // Add active class for the current item
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Aboce code listens to the `a href` link and manages the class toggle accordingly.